# Generic XTS Endpoints Function

Tags: r, xts

Is there a function that returns index for any integer increment of time? For xts, there are 'days', 'weekdays', etc. But what if I want 2 days, 6 days?

Comment: Look at ?`seq.POSIXt`

Comment: What do you want to do that the `k` argument to `endpoints` doesn't already do?

Comment: Joshua, I totally did not know that argument existed. That solves all my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `endpoints` function has an argument (`k`) for this:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
endpoints(x, "months")
# [1]   0  30  58  89 119 150 180
endpoints(x, "months", k=2)
# [1]   0  58 119 180
endpoints(x, "months", k=3)
# [1]   0  89 180
```